# Laravel and mamp

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I have a fresh install of laravel.  I setup the host to point to the public directory through mamp.  Nothing serves however after restarting the local server.

I replicated all of this on windows through WAMP and laravel serves correctly.  Redoing my steps on mac, the page just spins until the browser times it out.

Nothing fancy is happening, just trying to get the core laravel landing page to serve on a fresh laravel 5.4 install through mamp.

I went so far as to add a vhosts entry in the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra file.  Restarted the servers and still no dice.

Any suggestions or nudges in the right direction would be super helpful.  I just dont know what could be the difference at this point.  I can do it successfully on windows...

Nothing happens in the logs.  Browser just spins until it times out I'm guessing.  Nothing serves, not even a timeout error.

ls -l reveals:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 kstanley  staff    1050 Feb  3 16:49 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 kstanley  staff    1055 Feb  3 16:49 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  10 kstanley  staff     340 Feb 26 09:23 public
-rw-r--r--   1 kstanley  staff    2906 Feb  3 16:49 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 kstanley  staff     204 Feb 26 09:23 resources
drwxr-xr-x   6 kstanley  staff     204 Feb 26 09:18 routes
-rw-r--r--   1 kstanley  staff     563 Feb  3 16:49 server.php
drwxr-xr-x   6 kstanley  staff     204 Feb 26 09:23 storage
drwxr-xr-x   7 kstanley  staff     238 Feb 26 09:23 tests
drwxr-xr-x  33 kstanley  staff    1122 Feb 26 09:23 vendor
```

Comment: If you installed deps with composer and generated a new key with artisan it seems like a permission problem to me. Please post the contents of `/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error_log` and `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log` log files. Also open a terminal, cd to Laravel dir and post the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: I also tried the combo of "php artisan serve" with the mamp listing.  In the index file in /public i tried an echo and exit on the first line and its not even getting there.  Something is wrong I think with mamp maybe?  I dont get it, works on windows perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was a non issue with laravel.  The issue was mamp.  None of my other hosts worked either.  After doing a hard reboot of my computer and restarting mamp, everything worked.  This is not the first time this has happened with mamp.

Answer (score 0):

Remember always to set 777 permisions to storage folder `chmod -R 777 storage`.

It is common to get a blank screen or a "Log error" while the main error is just a permission one.